# Writing from cascalog to MySQL does not work. How to debug this?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, clojure, cascading, cascalog

I'm trying to write the result of a cascalog query into a MySQL-Database. For this, I'm using [cascading-jdbc](https://github.com/Cascading/cascading-jdbc) and following an example i found [here](https://gist.github.com/MrJaba/3053815). I'm using `cascading-jdbc-core` and `cascading-jdbc-mysql` in version `3.0.0`.

I'm executing precisely this code from my REPL:

```
 (let [data [["foo1" "bar1"]
             ["foo2" "bar2"]]
       query-params (into-array String ["?col1" "?col2"])
       column-names (into-array String ["col1" "col2"])
       update-params (into-array String ["?col1"])
       update-column-names (into-array String ["col1"])
       jdbc-tap (fn []
                  (let [scheme (JDBCScheme.
                                 (Fields. query-params)
                                 column-names
                                 nil
                                 (Fields. update-params)
                                 update-column-names)
                        table-desc (TableDesc.
                                     "test_table"
                                     query-params
                                     column-names
                                     (into-array String []))
                        tap (JDBCTap.
                               "jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.101:3306/test_db?user=root&password=my-secret-pw"
                               "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                               table-desc
                               scheme)]
                     tap))]
    (?<- (jdbc-tap)
         [?col1 ?col2]
         (data ?col1 ?col2)))
```

When I'm running the code, I'm seeing these logs inside the REPL:

```
15/12/11 11:08:44 INFO hadoop.FlowMapper: sinking to: JDBCTap{connectionUrl='jdbc:mysql://192.168.99.101:3306/test_db?user=root&password=my-secret-pw', driverClassName='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', tableDesc=TableDesc{tableName='test_table', columnNames=[?col1, ?col2], columnDefs=[col1, col2], primaryKeys=[]}}
15/12/11 11:08:44 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local1324562503_0006_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
15/12/11 11:08:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
15/12/11 11:08:44 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local1324562503_0006_m_000000_0' done.
15/12/11 11:08:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1324562503_0006_m_000000_0
15/12/11 11:08:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
```

Everything looks fine. However, no data is written. I checket with `tcpdump` that not even a connection with my local MySQL-database is being established. Also, when I change the JDBC-connection-string to obvious wrong values (user names that do not exist, a non-existing DB name and even a non-existing IP for the DB server), I get the same logs that do not complain about anything.

Also, changing the `jdbc-tap` to `stdout` produces the expected values.

I do not know at all how to debug this. Is there a possibility to produce error outputs? Right now, I have no clue what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using the wrong version of `cascading-jdbc`. Cascalog `2.1.1` is using Cascading `2.5.3`. Switching to a `2.5` version fixed the problem.

I was not able to see this from the error messages though (as there were none). One of the developers of `cascading-jdbc` was kind enough to [point this out](https://github.com/Cascading/cascading-jdbc/issues/27#issuecomment-164848279) to me.